# SQL- Do I need some kind of Count function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query a database that has about 10-11 columns, including a column of id's and a column of role codes.  Those are the 2 column that i'm interested in.

```
ID    ROLE
1     a
2     a
2     b
2     c
3     a
4     a
4     b
```

I need to count how many role codes exist for each ID.  (Basically like counting the number of times each id exists in the database)

Output should be something like this:

```
ID     Count
1      1
2      3
3      1
4      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use count distinct:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(DISTINCT ROLE) 
   FROM YOURTABLE
 GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: This works, thanks